# Add new column in sales order grid table in admin magento

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0

I want to add new column 'Item list' in sales order grid table in admin where it will show all the names of ordered items.
I updated in `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grip.php` page and it will show the correct output but the pagination and number of records  shows incorrect as per the data.
Please see the code that i changed in Grid.php page

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_item', '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('name'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.name SEPARATOR ", ")')));
 $collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                array('cev' => 'customer_entity_varchar'),
                '(main_table.customer_id = cev.entity_id AND cev.attribute_id = 141 AND main_table.customer_id IS NOT NULL)',
                array(
                    'admin_number' => 'cev.value',
                )
            ); 
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

and for adding column

```
$this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Item List'),
        'width'     => '200px',
        'index'     => 'name',
        'type'        => 'text',

    ));
```

when i removed the above code then everything is working fine. Please check it and tell me where i am doing mistake.
Thanks